# Transactions journal with impact 2.5 or IEEE internet of things journal with 9

Tags: journals, paper-submission, bibliometrics, web-of-science

I have to choose between a transaction journal on Network science and engineering  with impact factor ( 2.5) and IEEE internet of things journal with 9 impact. 
I know that people prefer transactions journals. What do you recommend me to do ? Which one is more better in my CV as a Ph.D. student.

Comment: Probably you need to understand why IoTJ has a high IF.   I note that IoTJ has many poor quality papers -- one reason is because of the high volume and quick turnaround time.    As for the aforementioned Trans., the quality of papers is high, but the community is much smaller or much more specialized as compared to the IoTJ community, which tends to be multi-disciplinary comprising of industry people to academics that work on all layers of the protocol stack.

Comment: Also because of the high volume, the editors of IoTJ have lots of discretion to reject papers and deem them to be 'out of scope'.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about your specific journals, but Impact Factor is a **fake** measure and should be ignored. Both the idea of measuring "impact" by number of citations and the methodology itself to collect such data are flawed, hence impact factors constitute meaningless information in most cases.

What is important are the norms in your scientific community. Ask your colleagues what is better. Do not look at "impact factors".